# Where do sharepoint hosted apps files live on 15 hive?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Where do sharepoint hosted apps files live on 15 hive? I'm looking for the files that were downloaded to sharepoint when an app was installed. unlike features, I'm not seeing where the provisioned files exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not in the 15 hive.  Any files needed by a SharePoint hosted app would be provisioned to that app's app web, which means they would ultimately be stored in a content database, not in the 15 hive.

Here are a couple MSDN articles on [the app model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887.aspx) and the [difference between host webs and app webs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179925.aspx).

Here also is a very helpful [series of blog posts by Chris O'Brien](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/08/sharepoint-2013-appsarchitecture.html) on the subject of app architecture.

Comment: I assume that means anything I need to do to debug it would require me to just querying the content db?

Comment: Theoretically I suppose yes, but reaching in to the content DBs is frowned upon by Microsoft, and additionally, I don't think the app's content DB is the same as the host web's content DB, so I don't even know which DB you would look at.